# Can Kindle previewer preview older Kindles?

Tags: kindle-previewer

Can Kindle previewer (from Amazon) preview what a document will look like on older Kindles?

Kindle previewer can preview Kindle:

- Paperwhite
- Touch
- fire
- Kindle for PC or Mac
- All other Kindle apps

Does it preview first generation Kindles (not apps)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can. In the Devices menu, select "Kindle e-ink", then from the tabs across the top select either "Kindle" or "Kindle DX" instead of "Kindle Paperwhite". This will show you the mobi (as opposed to the KF8) view, which is what the older devices use.[image]

Comment: we'll see how long that will last. the option "kindle" is already gone. i suggest whoever wants this option (mobi), turn off automatic updates and don't update `kindle prevuewer`. for "kindle DX" mighte also disappear

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, that's the only reliable preview you can get. All of the other preview modes are so flawed as to be useless to me. The root problem appears to be that for the KF8 modes, the previewer is unable to accurately reflect the interaction of the particular webkit version and hardware capabilities of the different devices.